# how to merge columns of two tables in SQL to form one final table with all columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In redshift, I have table A with 200 columns and Table B with 300 columns.Both these tables have only 2 common column. I want to create final table with all columns of A & B with common columns present only once. Is there easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the common columns appearing twice, use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE combined AS
(
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B USING (common_col1, common_col2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple join on those 2 matching columns
You could use these 2 columns as Diststyle and Sortkey to improve the performance too on redshift as `DISTKEY(col1, col2) and SORTKEY(col1, col2)`  for both the tables.

```
    Create table final as (
    Select * from A Join B
    On A.col1 =B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2) ;
```

Comment: this does not work for me.. It gave error column name "xyz" is duplicated;

Comment: Then just mention all the column names once for xyz dont mention A.xyz or B.xyz just mention xyz it will work or whichever columns are matching dont add tables alias just mention as that column once